# Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning demo restrictions

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I know that the demo for Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning has a 45 minute time limit, but how does it enforce that limit?

Is it 45 minutes of play time from starting up the game or creating a character, then thats it?

Or is it 45 minutes playing a character, then if you want to play some more, you need to start again with a new character, and can do so as many times as you like?

Also, does anyone know if they will let you use the save games from the demo in the full version? (assuming you can actually save the game, I'm still downloading it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 45 minute limit is from after your encounter with the Fateweaver after you leave the tower (the starting dungeon). From there it is 45 minutes of gameplay (menus and dialog stop the clock), and you would seem to be limited to the area around the village of Gorhart for the duration of the demo. Areas not available will have the shimmering barrier there.

Comment: Thanks! I assume that starting a new character resets the timer, since there appears to be no game saving feature?

Comment: It should. I haven't had time to do a new playthrough of the demo yet.

Answer (score 3):

To extend upon CyberSkull's answer:
No, the character you create in the demo does not carry over to the full game once you buy your copy. I just found that out over [here](http://reckoning.amalur.com/r/faq). Suuuper disappointed.